# how to go to the same page after login in php page

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a search page in which pop up is open and after pop up login I want to redirect the same URL which means that the URL is not changed. So how can I redirect?

this is the search page pop up code:

```
<div id="light">
    <form action="tutors_login1.php" method="post" name="form">

    <center>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            PLEASE LOGIN
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            User Email <input type="text" name="email" />
        </td></tr>
        </tr><td>
            Password <input type="password" name="password" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
        <input type="submit" name="submitbut" value="Login" />
        </td></tr>                   
    </table>
    </center>

    </form>
</div>

<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

this is the login page code in which I redirect the page

```
if($flagl=='lgin'){    
    header('Location: my_account.php');
}

$tabl = 'tutor';

if($_POST['submitbut'] == 'Login') {
    $stateid=$_REQUEST['country'];
    $cityid=$_REQUEST['state'];
    $areaid=$_REQUEST['city'];

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    
    $sql = "SELECT * from $tabl where email='$email' AND password='$password' AND app='1'";

    $exec = mysql_query($sql);

    $num = mysql_num_rows($exec);

    if($num == 1) {
        $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec);
        $_SESSION['login'] = $fetch['uniq'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $fetch['email'];
        
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
         
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'tutor';

        header("Location: latest_tuition_jobs.php");

    }
        if($sql1 = "SELECT * from $tabl where email='$email' AND password='$password' AND app='0'")
        {
            $exec1 = mysql_query($sql1);
            
            $flag_r1 = 'r';
} else {
        $flag_r = 'r';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

It's the `URL` from the page you're coming from to your login form.

Just redirect in `PHP` to this page after successful login.

Comment: this shouldn´t matter,
just check out what is written in REQUEST_URI

should be sth like /index.php

and ur current page could be login.php

so u came from index to ur login page

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

as per PHP docs it states :

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Which is interpreted as if you to try access a page that is log in only, then you will need to log in. Once you log in then the login will take you back to the referring or last page and you can go about your business.

Also please stop using MySql_ as it is a depretiated and should not be used for new code. (or even old code for that matter). Please refactor your code for PDO or you might fall victim to inject attacks. If you need help setting your PDO then please let me know and I will assist you :)